# Pathname /c:/filename.txt from hdfs://localhost:5050/c:/filename.txt is not a valid DFS filename

Tags: java, hadoop

i am running a simple wordcount program and getting output well, in same hdfs file system. but i need to put the output file in my local system like : c:/filename.txt. but while trying like this

```
conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);

        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("Input"));

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("c:/filename.txt"));
```

i am getting following error:

```
14/03/03 23:04:32 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /c:/filename.txt from hdfs://localhost:5050/c:/filename.txt is not a valid DFS filename.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1142)
    at org.raj.MapReduceDriver.main(MapReduceDriver.java:52)
```

is this possible to do, if it is pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the output file on your local Filesystem from a MapReduce program. The output path should be set to a directory on the HDFS.

You can copy the output directory to your local FS using the command `hadoop -getmerge <outputDir> <path in Local FS>`